The reason why the sum of the first 2024 terms of this sequence is incorrect?
The known conditions of the sequence are as follows:
s[n] == a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + ... ... + a[n]
a[1] == 1
a[2] == 2
a[n + 2] == (2 + RealAbs[Cos[(n  \[Pi])/2]]) a[n] - RealAbs[Sin[(n  \[Pi])/2]]

To find the sum of the first 2024 terms of this sequence, s[2024].

The method I used is as follows, but the result calculated is incorrect. What could be the reason?
sol = First@
   RSolve[{a[1] == 1, a[2] == 2, 
     a[n + 2] == (2 + RealAbs[Cos[(n  \[Pi])/2]]) a[n] -RealAbs[Sin[(n  \[Pi])/2]]}, a[n], n] // Simplify
a[n_] = a[n] /. sol
s[n_] = Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}]
s[2024] // Simplify


The 2 questions you've asked today are essentially the same. You should have edited this question to clarify it rather than asking a new question. Now, given the latter question is clearer and has received answer, I decide to mark this as a duplicate.

Here is an approach to deriving sum and analytic expression:
f = ((1-(-1)^#)/2) &;
g=((1-(-1)^(#-1))/2)&;
a[1] = 1;
a[2] = 2;
a[n_]:= (2+g[n])a[n-2] -f[n];
Total[a/@ Range[2024]]


Now for analytic expression:
s=FindSequenceFunction[Table[Total[a/@Range[j]],{j,10}],n]
s/.n->2024



Is it not possible to find the general term formula directly using the rsolve function? Is the general term formula obtained using the rsolve function incorrect?

You can try. I am away from computer and don’t have time unfortunately. Perhaps answer can serve as check. Good luck.

Note that "==" is "Equal" and "=" ist "Set". Further, you should use Memoisation to get more efficient code. Then:
a[1] = 1
a[2] = 2
a[n_] /; n > 2 := 
 a[n] = (2 + RealAbs[Cos[((n - 2)   \[Pi])/2]])  a[n - 2] - 
   RealAbs[Sin[((n - 2)   \[Pi])/2]]

With this:
Sum[a[i], {i, 1, 2024}]

7026026383756993599157004336979393539930298505078343743720129454108340\
1660253019851685076789108099905816217616900366203982893125406613501514\
0629603253812158478912520099620806333736049631015304211703308628891412\
7603956091560825529312578767885740368763779090938091833997112283321358\
1674783212961277076088634933425875580305355090127983913314225182629453\
3943282776302062925193048201372180284125118430805085267181901521079141\
377663761183299555842556929552909351648205908608502280972552452


What if I need to find its general term formula, a[n]?

There is no mistake in using a[1] == 1 in the rsolve function.

@csn899 in your first block of code you use ==.  If that's supposed to be merely descriptive, then it's fine, but if it's supposed to be code to produce s and a then you need the single = as in this post.

@evanb The first block is not code, it's just an explanation of the known conditions.

No need to solve the recursion if the goal is to sum the first several terms.
RecurrenceTable[{a[1] == 1, a[2] == 2, 
   a[n + 2] == (2 + RealAbs[Cos[(n π)/2]]) a[n] - 
     RealAbs[Sin[(n π)/2]]}, a, {n, 2024}] // Total



702602638375699359915700433697939353993029850507834374372012945410834016602530198516850767891080999058162176169003662039828931254066135015140629603253812158478912520099620806333736049631015304211703308628891412760395609156082552931257876788574036876377909093809183399711228332135816747832129612770760886349334258755803053550901279839133142251826294533943282776302062925193048201372180284125118430805085267181901521079141377663761183299555842556929552909351648205908608502280972552452

